# Ruby encoding issue showing weird characters on emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im on ruby 1.9.3p545 and Rails 3.0.20

I have a contact form and I'm sending the following email to the user when they fill it up:

```
Thank you for your inquiry Beverly,

This email is a receipt to confirm we have received your inquiry and `we'll` be in touch shortly.
```

My issue is it's showing `we&#x27;ll` instead of showing `we'll` , what would I need to do display the message properly?

My controller create action:

```
  def create
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(params[:inquiry])

    if @inquiry.save
      if @inquiry.ham?
        begin
          InquiryMailer.notification(@inquiry, request).deliver
        rescue
          logger.warn "There was an error delivering an inquiry notification.\n#{$!}\n"
        end

        begin
          InquiryMailer.confirmation(@inquiry, request).deliver
        rescue
          logger.warn "There was an error delivering an inquiry confirmation:\n#{$!}\n"
        end
      end

      redirect_to thank_you_inquiries_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

I'm using it on refinery-cms

on `app/views/inquiry_mailer/confirmation.html.erb`

I have: `<%= InquirySetting.confirmation_message(Globalize.locale).gsub("%name%", @inquiry.name) %>`

and on refinery settings have the following email:

```
Thank you for your inquiry %name%,

This email is a receipt to confirm we have received your inquiry and we'll be in touch shortly.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post your email template?

Comment: Updated my question, could you have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails sanitises the string of `InquirySetting.confirmation_message(Globalize.locale).gsub("%name%", @inquiry.name)`. It does this in order to prevent html tags and the like within possibly user provided strings to be rendered by the server. Otherwise your application would be [open to XSS attacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss).

If you know the string for the confirmation_message to not be user changeable contents you can deactivate Rails' security mechanism by [declaring the string as safe](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html). Do so by changing the contents of the template to `<%= raw InquirySetting.confirmation_message(Globalize.locale).gsub("%name%", @inquiry.name) %>`.

Again, please only do so if you trust the source of the template's contents.